# Can't store image in database

Tags: php, image, mysqli, upload

Every time I would upload a picture, it would say that it is successfully uploaded. When I check on the temp folder on my comp, yes it is store but when it comes to the database, it won't store any images I uploaded.

```
<?php

if($_POST)
{
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "pamphotos") or die('error in connection'.mysqli_connect_error());

    $caption = $_POST['caption'];
    $image_cont = 'c://uploads//';
    $image_cont2= 'c://uploads//thmb//';
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $src = $image_cont . $filename;
    $thumb = $image_cont2. $filename;


    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
    else
        {
            echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"c://uploads//" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

                    $q = "INSERT into photos(p_desc, p_src, p_thumbsrc) VALUES('$caption', '$src','$thumb')";

                    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $q) or die('error in connection'.mysqli_connect_error());

                        if($stmt)
                        {
                             echo "File succesfully Uploaded.";
                        }

            }
        }

}
```

Comment: When I made my first social network I just stored the files in a directory and then just stored the path in the mySQL DB. I think it would be beneficial for you to do the same. Plus it makes it easier to handle unlinking the files whenever new ones are uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have thought about that too but i really don't know how to.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on where should i start to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You are using [prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) for your INSERT statement, but you don't [execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) it.  So the row is not inserted to the database.

Here's how I would write the part where you run the query:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare($q);
if ($stmt === false)
{
    trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
if ($stmt->execute() === false) {
    trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
echo "File succesfully Uploaded.";
```

---

PS: It's a bit tangential to your question, but you should use query parameters instead of interpolating variables into your query.  You are at risk for SQL injection.

Comment: Oh yeah! I forgot about that. THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH SIR! 
Excuse my forgetfulness.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation sir. I'll be implementing this to my code right now. Info's very helpful.

Comment: @RedSparkle you can get rid of these boring conditions if use mysqli_report() to make mysqli raise errors automatically.